# passing value from mainactivity to a listview

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi everyone I am currently developing an android app, I am having some confusions in the code, I have a main activity in which I store some array values.
I have two xml files(one mainactivity.xml and other the other one is listview.xml)

In main activity.xml there are four switches, when I click any particular switch it should take me to the listview.xml, with a corresponding array displayed on list view by list view adapter. The code is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


ListView l;

 Button chem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
 public String[] contentc = {
            "Abundance",
            "Anxiety",
            "Bruxism",
            "Discipline",
            "Drug Addiction"
        };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_element, contentp);
    chem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING! {RUN SOME FUNCTION ... DO CHECKS... ETC}
            setContentView(R.layout.list);

            l.setAdapter(adapter);  



        } 
    });






}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity2.this, activity1.class);
intent.putExtra("message", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity1, in onCreate(), you can get the String message by retrieving a Bundle (which contains all the messages sent by the calling activity) and call getString() on it :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message")
```